# Regex to find substring starting with [ ]

Tags: python, regex

The below is the sample substring present in a much larger string (detaildesc_final) that I have obtained. I need to use a regex search across the string so that I can retrieve all the lines that begin with " [] " (The two square brackets I mean) from the [Data] Section. All lines should be retrieved in the [Data] section until the [Logs] line is encountered.

```
[Data]

[] some text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[Logs]
```

I'm using Python to work the code and I've used the following command (which clearly is incorrect).

```
re.findall(r'\b\\[\\]\w*', detaildesc_final)
```

I need the result to be in the following format:

```
some text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text
```

I have already looked a lot online and I could figure out to find any line starting with a single double character instead of two ( [] in this case).
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Regex doesn't seem the right tool here. What are you intending to do with the matches?

Comment: There's also `str.startswith()`; and then you can use indexing of a string to remove the first 2 or 3 characters.

Comment: Use: `re.findall(r'\[\]\s*(.+)', detaildesc_final)`

Comment: Is there context before/after the `[Data]`/`[Logs]` that you *don't* want to match?

Comment: There are 2 steps here: 1) Find the blocks between `Data` and `Logs`, then 2) extract the lines starting with `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need positive look behind :

```
import re

pattern=r'(?<=\[\])(.\w.+)'

string_1="""[Data]

[] some text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[Logs]"""


match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1,re.M)
for item in match:
    print(item.group(1))
```

output:

```
 some text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
 some_other_text
```

> Regex explanation :

```
Positive Lookbehind (?<=\[\])
```

> It tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string,
>   to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there.

- `\[` matches the character `[` literally (case sensitive)
- `\]` matches the character `]` literally (case sensitive)
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `+` Quantifier `—` Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: All answers worked perfectly well. Although this was the one I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't over-complicate things.

```
for line in detaildesc_final.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('[]'):
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

str = """
[Data]

[] some text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[] some_other_text

[Logs]
"""


print re.sub("([[a-zA-Z ]{0,}][ ]?)", '',str)
```

**output:**

```
some text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text

some_other_text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall(r'\[\] (.*)\n\n', detaildesc_final)
```

Output:

```
['some text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text',
 'some_other_text']
```